# How do I get auto address when using structural directives?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, angular6

[image]

Hi I am not getting this auto address when I am using `*ngIf` or trying to append the `div`, otherwise its working completely fine.
What am I supposed to do to get this auto address along with `*ngIf` and appending it.

```
<div class="form-group label-floating">
    <label class="control-label">Address1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control search-address" name="address1" placeholder=" " [(ngModel)]="address1" #address1>
</div>
```

In the above code auto address is working

```
<div *ngIf="isShow">
    <div class="form-group label-floating" *ngFor="let place of places">
        <label class="control-label">Place</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control search-address" name="address2" placeholder=" " [(ngModel)]="place.address2" #address2>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code auto address is not working and the only difference is I am using structural directives.

my ts code

```
const address1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.address1.nativeElement, { componentRestrictions: { country: 'IN' }, types: [this.adressType]
 }); 
google.maps.event.addListener(address1, 'place_changed', () => { this.place = address1.getPlace(); this.invokeEvent(this.place); 
});
```

Please suggest me a good solution where I can use all three of them.
Thank You.

Comment: You are getting the input box or not??

Comment: Are you sure that "places" holds any data? And if so could you please provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: Try again after removing the `*ngIf="isShow"` from your places parent div, and check whether it is working or not ?

Comment: Rohan Kumar - I tried removing *ngIf and *ngFor. It was working after that.